# Getting Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" when using SparkContext.setLogLevel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, slf4j

I'm changing the Log Level of my SparkContext using `sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")`, and when I run the program, I get:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details
```

Everything still runs as usual, but I'm wondering where this is coming from, as I haven't manually inserted any SLF4J dependency.
My POM dependency section looks like this (where `scala.version` is 2.11.8 and `scala.binaty.version` is 2.11):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalaj-http_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
        <artifactId>lift-json_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-M8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea what's causing this, and how I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that one of your dependencies have a specific version of `slf4j` that overrides the one that Spark uses, which cause that error.

I advise you to explicitly put the `slf4j` dependencies in your `pom.xml`

For example:

```
<properties>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.7.5</org.slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

In addition, make sure you have a valid `log4j.xml` file which stored in your classpath, and try to set the log level of Spark in the xml instead of using the code.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <logger name="org.apache.spark">
    <level value="error"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.spark-project">
    <level value="error"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.spark-project">
    <level value="error"/>
  </logger>

  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have a `log4j.xml` configuration file?

Comment: No, just found out it exists :) Do I need in the same folder as the `pom.xml`? Will the basic one from https://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat will do?

Comment: Just need to make sure the file is located within the classpath.

Comment: Try to put it under `resources` directory.

Comment: I changed the `slf4j` version in the answer, try to replace the version to `1.7.5` and check if works.

Comment: No :( Now the error looks like this: `[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 4]SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`

Comment: I suggested you in the answer (updated) to avoid changing the log level in the code, and instead do it in the `log4j.xml`. Try do that and check if works.

Comment: I think it is related to an inner dependency of Spark, which has its own logging..

Comment: I have the same configuration as well and it works just fine:\. Although I use Scala 2.10.4 and Spark 1.5.2.

Comment: It seems to be Spark related.. never mind, I can deal with these 3 lines. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure. No problem :)